# How to indicate to mypy an object has certain attributes?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, duck-typing

I am using some classes that derived from a parent class (`Widget`); among the children, some have certain attributes (`posx` and `posy`) but some don't.

```py
import enum
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


class Color(enum.IntEnum):
    GLOWING_IN_THE_DARK = enum.auto()
    BROWN_WITH_RAINBOW_DOTS = enum.auto()


@dataclass
class Widget:
    """Generic class for widget"""


@dataclass
class Rectangle(Widget):
    """A Color Rectangle"""

    posx: int
    posy: int
    width: int = 500
    height: int = 200
    color: Color = Color.BROWN_WITH_RAINBOW_DOTS


@dataclass
class Group(Widget):
    children: List[Widget]


@dataclass
class Button(Widget):
    """A clickable button"""

    posx: int
    posy: int
    width: int = 200
    height: int = 100
    label: str = "some label"
```

Even after doing some filtering with only widgets with these attributes, `mypy` is not able to recognize that they should have.

Is there a way to indicate to `mypy` that we have an object with a given attribute?

For example, the following function and call:

```py
def some_function_that_does_something(widgets: List[Widget]):
    """A useful docstring that says what the function does"""
    widgets_with_pos = [w for w in widgets if hasattr(w, "posx") and hasattr(w, "posy")]

    if not widgets_with_pos:
        raise AttributeError(f"No widget with position found among list {widgets}")

    first_widget = widgets_with_pos[0]
    pos_x = first_widget.posx
    pos_y = first_widget.posy
    print(f"Widget {first_widget} with position: {(pos_x, pos_y)}")


some_widgets = [Group([Rectangle(0, 0)]), Button(10, 10, label="A button")]
some_function_that_does_something(some_widgets)
```

would return a result as expected: `Widget Button(posx=10, posy=10, width=200, height=100, label='A button') with position: (10, 10)`

But `mypy` would complain:

```py
__check_pos_and_mypy.py:53: error: "Widget" has no attribute "posx"
        pos_x = first_widget.posx
                ^
__check_pos_and_mypy.py:54: error: "Widget" has no attribute "posy"
        pos_y = first_widget.posy
                ^
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How to do?

Maybe, one way could be to change the design of the classes:

- Subclass of `Widget` with the position (e.g. `WidgetWithPos`)
- `Rectangle` and `Button` would derive from this class
- We indicate in our function: `widget_with_pos: List[WidgetWithPos] = ...`

... however, I cannot change the original design of the classes and `mypy` might still complain with something like:

`List comprehension has incompatible type List[Widget]; expected List[WidgetWithPos]`

Of course, we could put a bunch of `# type:ignore` but that will clutter the code and I am sure there is a smarter way ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small variation on Alex Waygood's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69336474/1393162), to remove the `cast`. The trick is to put the [@runtime_checkable](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable) decorator on the Protocol class. It simply makes `isinstance()` do the `hasattr()` checks.

```
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

# Protocol has been added in Python 3.8+
# so this makes the code backwards-compatible
# without adding any dependencies
# (typing_extensions is a MyPy dependency already)

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
else:
    from typing_extensions import Protocol, runtime_checkable


@dataclass
class Widget:
    """Generic class for widget"""


@runtime_checkable
class WithPos(Protocol):
    """Minimum interface of all widgets that have a position"""
    posx: int
    posy: int


def some_function_that_does_something(widgets: List[Widget]):
    """A useful docstring that says what the function does"""
    widgets_with_pos = [w for w in widgets if isinstance(w, WithPos)]

    if not widgets_with_pos:
        raise AttributeError(f"No widget with position found among list {widgets}")

    first_widget = widgets_with_pos[0]
    pos_x = first_widget.posx
    pos_y = first_widget.posy
    print(f"Widget {first_widget} with position: {(pos_x, pos_y)}")
```

The following code (using the other sub-classes defined in the original question) [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=604be9f3da8f417eb4d7e882e44e6915):

```py
w1 = Group([])
w2 = Rectangle(2, 3)
some_function_that_does_something([w1, w2])
```

---

**Further reading**

For reference, here are some of the links Alex included in his answer:

- [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for `typing.Protocol`
- [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), introducing `typing.Protocol` and explaining the concept of structural subtyping.
- [MyPy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) for `Protocol`s and structural subtyping.

Comment: That's a really nice idea. I didn't think of using the runtime_checkable decorator.

Comment: @AlexWaygood I picked it up while reading PEP 544. :)

Comment: Awesome. Let's mark it as accepted answer because the code looks nicer.

Comment: I support having this as the accepted answer. The code is cleaner, less repetitive, and more efficient at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `typing.Protocol` and `typing.cast` to solve this. `typing.Protocol` allows us to define "[structural types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system?wprov=sfti1)" — types that are defined by *attributes* or *properties* rather than the classes they inherit from — and `typing.cast` is a function that has no effect at runtime, but allows us to assert to the type-checker that an object has a certain type.

Note that `Protocol` has been added in Python 3.8 so for 3.7 (3.6 does not support `dataclasses`, although it also has a backport), we need to use `typing_extensions` (which is a dependency of `mypy` by the way).

```
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import cast, List

# Protocol has been added in Python 3.8+
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import Protocol
else:
    from typing_extensions import Protocol


@dataclass
class Widget:
    """Generic class for widget"""


class WidgetWithPosProto(Protocol):
    """Minimum interface of all widgets that have a position"""
    posx: int
    posy: int


def some_function_that_does_something(widgets: List[Widget]):
    """A useful docstring that says what the function does"""

    widgets_with_pos = [
        cast(WidgetWithPosProto, w)
        for w in widgets
        if hasattr(w, "posx") and hasattr(w, "posy")
    ]

    if not widgets_with_pos:
        raise AttributeError(f"No widget with position found among list {widgets}")

    first_widget = widgets_with_pos[0]
    pos_x = first_widget.posx
    pos_y = first_widget.posy
    print(f"Widget {first_widget} with position: {(pos_x, pos_y)}")
```

This [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=71bd31e2b9cd4873bccce12408ccf139).

---

**Further reading:**

- [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for `typing.Protocol`
- [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), introducing `typing.Protocol` and explaining the concept of structural subtyping.
- [MyPy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) for `Protocol`s and structural subtyping.
- [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) for `typing.cast`.
- [MyPy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html) for `typing.cast`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex: awesome! By the way, we are using Python 3.7 so I have updated your answer to mention the backport we need. And it looks nicer to have the `cast` at the level of the element rather than the overall list.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. great! Thanks for the point regarding when `Protocol` was introduced. I personally try to use `cast` as little as possible, as it does introduce a *tiny* amount of runtime cost, even though it returns the element unchanged — that's why I used it at the level of the overall list in my original answer. But that's just a matter of personal preference :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment about runtime usage

Comment: This answer was helpful for me because, in addition to showing how to really use Protocol in a clear and complete example, it also got me to read PEP 544. Previously, I had looked at the documentation of [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), didn't understand it, and moved on. Now I'm already putting it to use… :)

Comment: Shucks, well if you haven't just put a smile on my face @BenKovitz. Thanks so much for your comment :)