# Function for restricting the type of attributes in an object (Python, mypy)

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Example setup:

```py
from typing import Optional


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a: Optional[int] = None
        
    def check_a(self) -> bool:
        return self.a is not None
        
a = A()
if a.check_a():
    print(a.a + 1)  # error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
```

The `check_a` method checks what type of variable `a` is, but `mypy` does not see this and writes an error. `TypeGuard` will not help, because it can create a function to check the type, and not a function to check the type of an object variable

Is it possible to somehow make mypy notice this in order to use the function to check the type of the variable `self.a` without explicitly referring to it in the check? (Use `if a.a_check` instead of `if a.a is not None`)?

Comment: You know that the error would never occur, as during runtime that piece of code can only be executed when `a.a` is not `None`. However, `mypy` doesn't take runtime values into account and from the point of view of a compiler `a.a` could be either an `int` or `None`. And `None + 1` should generate an error.

Comment: I know this, but is it possible to prove it somehow for `mypy`?

Comment: [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)?

Comment: @deceze In more detail, please

Comment: `from typing import cast` `print(cast(int, a.a) + 1)`

Comment: Hmm, as an option, but it's not very convenient to check every time

Comment: You do have a "manual" check that type checkers don't understand, so you will also need to make the type checker manually understand your asserted status, which is what `cast` is for. I don't think there's another way to make the type checker understand `a.check_a()`; but I could be wrong…

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: I tried to do it through TypeGuard, but can it be applied here with `self`?

Comment: Apologies @Lev145, I was a bit too trigger-happy with voting to close. I think there's two ways of doing it with TypeGuard — see here. I'll vote to reopen and happily add it as an answer if it is reopened. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=a22475b0e8775f60d718d91eaaf90a3a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways in which this can be done with [the new `TypeGuard` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002167/how-to-create-a-user-defined-type-assertion-in-python/69003897#69003897), which can be imported from `typing` in  Python 3.10, and is available from [the PyPI `typing_extensions` package](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) in earlier Python versions. Note that `typing_extensions` is already a dependency of Mypy, so if you're using Mypy, you likely already have it.

The first option is to change your `check_a` method to a `staticmethod` that takes in a variable that might be `int` or `None` as an input, and verifies whether or not it is an `int`. (Apologies, I have changed the names of some of your variables, as I found it quite confusing to have a class `A` that also had an `a` attribute.)

```
from typing import TypeGuard, Optional

class Foo1:
    def __init__(self, bar: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.bar = bar
    
    @staticmethod
    def check_bar(bar: Optional[int]) -> TypeGuard[int]:
        return bar is not None
        

f1 = Foo1()
if f1.check_bar(f1.bar):
    print(f1.bar + 1)
```

The second option is to use [structural subtyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331673/how-to-indicate-to-mypy-an-object-has-certain-attributes) to assert that an instance of class `Foo` (or class `A` in your original question) has certain properties at a certain point in time. This requires altering the test method so that it becomes a `classmethod`, and is a little more complex to set up, but leads to a nicer check once you have it set up.

```
from typing import TypeGuard, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar

class HasIntBar(Protocol):
    bar: int


F = TypeVar('F', bound='Foo2')


class Foo2:
    def __init__(self, bar: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.bar = bar
    
    @classmethod
    def check_bar(cls: type[F], instance: F) -> TypeGuard[HasIntBar]:
        return instance.bar is not None
        

f2 = Foo2()
if Foo2.check_bar(f2): # could also write this as `if f2.check_bar(f2)`
    print(f2.bar + 1)
```

You can try both of these options out on Mypy playground [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=4083d24a46382e3550c66fb406b7cd00).

Comment: I'm doing it this way now, I'd be wondering if it's possible to do it differently, but apparently it's impossible, thanks

Comment: @Lev145 yes, I agree it's imperfect, but I think it's the best that's currently possible :)

Comment: Maybe they'll add it later

Comment: It seems [narrowing down `self` with TypeGuard is not intended on purpose](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/#narrowing-of-implicit-self-and-cls-parameters): “A concern was raised that there may be cases where it is desired to apply the narrowing logic on self and cls. This is an unusual use case, […] It was therefore decided that no special provision would be made for it. If narrowing of self or cls is required, the value can be passed as an explicit argument to a type guard function.” So above solutions may keep the only ones possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as far as the type checker is concerned, your `bool` says nothing about the type of your `.a`. For example, you could have written

```
class A:
    ...

    def check_a(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

However, as you probably know, mypy can rule out `None` within an `if x is not None:`. Your problem is that you've split your `if x is not None:` between the function definition and call site, so mypy can't use it to infer the value's not `None`.

What you can do to fix this is pass the operation you want to do to the `A`, in which case you'd have something like what's called `foreach` in other languages. In the context of `Optional` (and `A` is a wrapper around a mutable `Optional`) this can apply a function to values *if they exist*.

```
class A:
    ...

    def foreach(self, f: Callable[[int], None]) -> None:
        if self.a is not None:
            f(self.a)

a = A()
a.foreach(lambda x: print(x + 1))
```

Note I don't have a `check_a` here.

Comment: I understand this, but it does not solve the problem, it will not be convenient to use in the code

Comment: @Lev145 you may need to add more information as to why you want to do this. As it is, it's not clear why you don't just use `if a.a is not None:`. I assume you don't do that because there are parts of your actual problem that don't work well with that that have been lost in making it a minimal example. It would be helpful to know more. Either way, as it stands, this question probably is a duplicate